# Parsing a xml doc with nested repetitive element names with DOM parser Java.

Tags: java, xml, parsing, dom, nested

I'm trying to parse an XML doc which looks something like what is bellow:

```
<!-- language: lang-xml -->
<map>
 <entry>
  <string>rowId : 1231231</string>
  <map>
   <entry>
    <string>some strings</string>
   </entry>
   <entry>
    </string>some more strings!</string>
   </entry>
  </map>
 </entry>
</map>
```

I always use getElementsByTagName method when I'm parsing xml files. but in this case I don't know how to get only the outer  element and then the inner one. It seems that by calling getElementsByTagName ("entry") will return also the inner elements.

Any suggestion on how to parse this doc?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You suspicions that `getElementsByTagName()` won't work for your problem are correct.  The [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/class-use/NodeList.html) from `org.w3c.dom.NodeList` says that `getElementsByTagName()`

> Returns a NodeList of all the Elements in document order with a given tag name and are contained in the document.

To parse properly, you will have to use XPath.  Here is some sample code which will obtain all the `<entry>` tags:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = builder.parse("yourfile.xml");
XPathFactory xPathfactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
XPath xpath = xPathfactory.newXPath();
XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("//entry");

Object set = expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);

NodeList list = (NodeList) set;
int count = list.getLength();
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    Node node = list.item(i);
    // Handle the entry node here
}
```